# Can adding a new column and making it a pk to a table break existing code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Working with a legacy system, many tables have no primary keys. DB is MSSQL server 2008, db was migrated from foxpro years ago.

I would like to add PK to the tables without them, but am getting push back "because it may break something."

Try as I might I can think of no realistic scenario where that can occur. The people pushing back cannot give me an example either they just want to be "safe". Being safe is leading to inaction which is causing unnecessary work. Anyway, can anyone give me a realistic scenario where this could cause an issue in existing .net code? Or confirm that it will not break existing code.

Reasoning for adding PK, is to be able to use Entity Framework to generate a DAL. There are issues with some tables where there is no suitable PK. Perhaps I should have asked what are the risks of adding a new column to an existing table? However this is done very frequently to some of these tables with no problems.

Comment: When you say Primary key, do you mean that currently there is *no* UNIQUE index on the fields that would you be declaring to be PK? Or, do such indexes exist already?

Comment: There are two basic scenarios I have. 1) existing column can be made into PK, currently not auto-increment, would leave that way, column has no issue with uniqueness or nulls. 2) no suitable column exists, add column, make it auto-increment. Indexes will be the next step :(

Comment: Should have also mentioned that added columns would go to the end of existing fields, not changing ordinal position.

Comment: If some columns are being used like PKs (i.e. Unique and possible referenced from elsewhere like a foreign key), then adding a UNIQUE index ought not to be an issue. 
I don't see any advantage to adding a new generated/auto-increment PK field, and it comes with the risks that come with any field-additions, and also with extra issues that may not arise with non-key added-fields. Do you see some advantage to adding such fields when nobody is going to be using them?

Comment: edited question as to why. The main reason is to be able to use EF to generate a DAL. And yes some fields are used as a FK, but are not specified as such (on todo list). We are also planning to some degree, normalize the database. Currently there is at least one table with +150 columns and growing that could benefit from normalization. but first I'd like to have PK, FK fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much as I hate to help you use Entity Framework, I have to say that if you have checked the column to make sure there are no nulls and no duplicates, you should be fine to declare it as a PK. Adding a new column is riskier but making an existing column a PK should be fairly straightforward and frankly if anything breaks as a result (i.e., it tried to insert a duplicate when you didn't want any), then that is good because if the column is supposed to be unique it is a bug if something tries to make it not unique.

What your company needs though is a clear understanding of how to successfully refactor databases, so that they don't feel it is not possible. I highly suggest you read, Refctoring Databases by
Ambler and Sadalage. ([http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Databases-Evolutionary-Addison-Wesley-Signature-ebook/dp/B001QAP36E/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1385070572&sr=1-1&keywords=refactoring+databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001QAP36E)). There are methods to reduce risk in refacctoring datbases.

Comment: the book is on order.

Answer (score 1):

There are no guarantees.

One area where I can imagine breakage is SELECT * statements and code that expects a certain number of columns in a certain order coming back. Adding a column, PK or not, could break that.

But adding a PK for the sake of a PK doesn't really add value. A PK helps CRUD (especially the UD parts :) ) so you'd have to change code to take advantage of that.

Comment: Not sure how I got two copies of this guys - tried to edit, ended up with two!

Answer (score 1):

If you're choosing to Auto Increment any of these newly created Primary Keys, you might run into Identity Insert issues.

Comment: This should not be a problem. When I make an existing column a PK, I would not make it auto-increment. I would allow it to keep being populated as is. The current columns must be usable as a PK, no nulls, no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lower environment and make the Primary Key changes you want and fully test the application. The only one I could think of was the same as the answer by @n8wrl.

If your legacy app uses names for the fields it pulls, you should be fine. Its risky if your app uses say : `myDataReader(0).toString()`

If you can make sure the added field is the last one in the table then I suppose even that is mitigated. I know how you feel but your team is using the "S**T Happens" argument. Its risky to mess with Primary Keys. You also need to ask yourself if any other apps in the company rely on this database.  I would say "Be very careful, and take backups". In theory I cant see any reason why it cant be done.

Comment: I'm feeling it's being used as an excuse to do nothing. PK are preventing Entity Framework from being used easily. After generating a DAL, I have to massage it to get it to work. I want to be able to generate the DAL without having to "fix" it. Wide tables (more than 23 columns) and no PK are one cause of grief.